# return error code : 401, No license found for the given deviceId

Tags: authentication, here-api

i have use this api
curl -X POST 
https://tracking.api.here.com/v2/token
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {signedRequest}'

my php code is

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://tracking.api.here.com/v2/timestamp');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {

```
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
```

}

$result = json_decode($result);

curl_close($ch);

$timestamp = ($result->timestamp);

$accessKey = $deviceId;

$secret = $deviceSecret;

$url = "https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token";

$nonce = mt_rand(100000,999999);

$timestamp = $timestamp;

$baseString = "grant_type=client_credentials&oauth_consumer_key=".$accessKey."&oauth_nonce=".$nonce."&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=".$timestamp."&oauth_version=1.0";

$workingString = array();

foreach (explode('&', $baseString) as $parameter) {

```
$parameter = explode('=', $parameter);

$workingString[] = urlencode($parameter[0]).'='.trim(urlencode($parameter[1]));
```

}

$urlEncodeParamaterString = implode('&', $workingString);

$fullBaseString = "POST&".urlencode($url)."&".urlencode($urlEncodeParamaterString);
$hashKey = $secret.'&';

function encode($data) {

```
return str_replace(['+', '/'], ['-', '_'], base64_encode($data));
```

}

function decode($data) {

```
return base64_decode(str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $data));
```

}

$binaryKey = decode($hashKey);

$signature = encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $fullBaseString, $binaryKey, true));

$authHeader = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=".$accessKey.",oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA256',oauth_timestamp='".$timestamp."',oauth_nonce=".$nonce.",oauth_version='1.0',oauth_signature=".$signature."";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://tracking.api.here.com/v2/token');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();

$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

$headers[] = 'Authorization: '.$authHeader;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {

```
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
```

}

curl_close($ch);

echo '';
print_r($result);

output
{
code: 401,
id: "312f56e5-db4f-40f5-807f-c5a0413dd668",
message: "No license found for the given deviceId.",
error: "*Timestamp wrong* When the request timestamp has a more than 10 second difference from the server time, the `x-here-timestamp` header with the current server timestamp is added to the response. *Incorrect Signature* If the OAuth signature is incorrect, the response will be a 401 but *without* the `x-here-timestamp` field. "
}

Answer (score 1):

In order to tracking a Device using HERE Tracking Service all you'll need to login and Create your Device ID First.

Please see below getting start documentation.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/tracking/dev_guide/topics/getting-started-1-creating-a-device-licence.html